# C# My while loop repeats 3 times before it prompts for another choice

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am new to C# but I know Java pretty well.  I may be missing something simple that I am just not aware of because of being new to this particular language.  I am trying to make a while loop that repeats until the user chooses Q. The loop exits fine but the code inside are repeated 3 times before it stops to prompt the user for a choice. Why would this happen?

```
class MainClass
{


    public static void DisplayMenu() {
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("(D)eposit");
        Console.WriteLine("(W)ithdraw");
        Console.WriteLine("(C)alculateInterest");
        Console.WriteLine("(S)howBalance");
        Console.WriteLine("(Q)uit");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Make choice by entering first letter of choice,");
        Console.WriteLine("then press ENTER key:");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Account account = new Account();
        char choice;
        double amount = 0.0;

        Console.WriteLine("************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Bernard's Bodacious Bank!");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("We have opened your account");
        DisplayMenu();
        choice = Char.ToUpper((char)Console.Read());

        while (!choice.Equals('Q')) {

            DisplayMenu();
            choice = Char.ToUpper((char)Console.Read()); 

        }

        account.ShowTransactions();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably an unhandled exception that is thrown somewhere. You could add a try/catch block or attach your debugger and make sure it catches all clr exceptions.

Comment: If you telling them to press enter you should use Console.ReadLine(). Also you may want to clear screen after they press enter since you redrawing the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is likely because you are using `Console.Read()`, which will process the next character in the input stream, which includes the `\n` and `\r` characters from when the user pressed `Enter`. These characters are then immediately processed inside your loop on the calls to `Console.Read()`.

If you just want a single character, you could instead use `Console.ReadKey()`, which returns the first key (as type `ConsoleKeyInfo`) that the user types. You can then do a comparison on it's `Key` property like:

```
Console.WriteLine("************************************");
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Bernard's Bodacious Bank!");
Console.WriteLine("************************************");
Console.WriteLine("We have opened your account");

double amount = 0.0;
ConsoleKeyInfo choice;

do
{
    DisplayMenu();
    choice = Console.ReadKey();
} while (choice.Key != ConsoleKey.Q);
```

---

Alternatively, if you **DO** want to allow them to press enter, then you should use the `Console.ReadLine()` method and check to see what it `StartsWith`:

```
DisplayMenu();
string choice = Console.ReadLine();

while (!choice.StartsWith("Q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    DisplayMenu();
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

Here's an example of how you might process input. It assumes you have methods that can be called for each choice:

```
var quit = false;

while(!quit)
{
    DisplayMenu();

    var choice = Console.ReadKey();

    switch (choice.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.D:
            Deposit();
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.W:
            Withdrawl();
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.C:
            CalcInterest();
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.S:
            ShowBalance();
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.Q:
            quit = true;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry, try again");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this statement is correct: "The reason is likely because you are using Console.Read(), which will return the entire line..."  The MSDN documentation for Console.Read() says it returns the next character from the input stream.  Yes, it will block until the user hits Enter, but each call will only return a single character, as opposed to the whole line.

Comment: You're right, let me try to correct that. The entire line becomes part of the input stream, but `Read()` only processes one character.

Comment: I thought that was the case. I need to then take the choice character and use it in a switch case inside the loop.  the do while with readkey made it alot more complicated than it should be. I am not sure I can use this either.  I am letting someone use a single bank account so I need to let the switch statement decide based on the fist character entered.  I could do nested if statements with the above solution but that seems messier than it should be.

Comment: What a weird method, `Console.Read`. If the line contains a character from outside Unicode plane 0, such as , will that character lead to two invocations of `Read`, returning the `int` representations of the surrogate pair components (UTF-16 style), or lead to only one `Read` returning the UTF-32 value, here `0x1F010` or `126992`?

Comment: @benjaminhmlucas You can just use the `.KeyChar` of your `ConsoleKeyInfo` value (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that's what I ended up with.  Code is working rgreat now... like you said what a weird method Console.Read is.....

Comment: @benjaminhmlucas The Do/While is basically identical to what you have, and is orthogonal to the problem statement. You could certainly use a switch inside the loop and call the appropriate methods based on the input. I've updated the answer with an example of how you might process input using the `KeyChar`.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN documentation:

> The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it terminates when you press the Enter key. Pressing Enter appends a platform-dependent line termination sequence to your input (for example, Windows appends a carriage return-linefeed sequence). Subsequent calls to the Read method retrieve your input one character at a time. After the final character is retrieved, Read blocks its return again and the cycle repeats.

In Windows, a "platform-dependent line termination sequence" is equal to `\r\n`. So when you type `A`, then Enter, you are actually sending 3 keystrokes for your program to process.

Also from the MSDN documentation:

> The ReadLine method, or the KeyAvailable property and ReadKey method are preferable to using the Read method.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the simplest answer, Use the read key method then use the choice.Key and ConsoleKey.Q.  Thanks for the help though guys! It pointed me in the right direction!

static void Main(string[] args) {

```
        Account account = new Account();
        double amount = 0.0;
        ConsoleKeyInfo choice;

        Console.WriteLine("************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Bernard's Bodacious Bank!");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("We have opened your account");
        DisplayMenu();
        choice = Console.ReadKey();
        while (choice.Key != ConsoleKey.Q) {
            switch (choice.Key) {
                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    Console.WriteLine("found d!");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Input Error!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        account.ShowTransactions();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```